# No output when checking an element in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have declared a string ArrayList in Java, now when I fill the entire list and I check if one element is inside with the `ArrayList.contains(value)` method and I want to print if it exists or not I get no output. I am wondering why as the `list.contains("Red")` method should return *TRUE*.

**Code snippet**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public MyClass{
    public static void main(){

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(10);

    list.add("Green");
    list.add("Orange");
    list.add("Red");
    list.add("Black");
    list.add("White");

    boolean test = list.contains("Red");

    if(test)
        System.out.println("True");

    else
        System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tested your code and it prints "True", there is no problem in the code itself

Comment: Delete the jar and recompile it. Then execute it again

Comment: The code works fine....Please use List "List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(10);"

Comment: Hint: instead of "if true print true, else print false" you can just System.out.println(test);

Comment: @VelNaga even better: List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Also There is a class modifier missing in your class "public class MyClass" not "public MyClass"

Comment: @VelNaga thank you! worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code, It works in my local, There are a couple of things missing in your code, **Class** modifier is missing and there is not "**String[] args**".Also, I did a bit of refactoring of your code. Hope this helps for you

```
package com.sample.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Green");
        list.add("Orange");
        list.add("Red");
        list.add("Black");
        list.add("White");

        boolean test = list.contains("Red");
        System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Alan This should be the answer to your question. "String[] args" alone is not enough Without class modifier you cannot run the class at all.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. Thanks for the useful answer!

Comment: @Alan Thank you and let's help others.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is OK in your code. But argument is missing. As JVM starts executing the java program it searches for the main method having this signature(i.e String array).

So your Main Method should be like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

And class modifier also missing in your class.

Use `public class MyClass` instead of `public MyClass`

Comment: obviously the correct answer, well done for spotting that

Comment: @PeterWalser Also class modifier is missing in his class

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem only partly.. I also have forgotten class tag on top.